SpringBoot JdbcTemplate setting db credentials outside application.properties
When using JdbcTemplates in SpringBoot app, generally we set below two fields in application.properties like
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=admin

Then @Autowire JdbcTemplate in our application and run our query. Is it allowed to configure spring.datasource.password=admin using java code instead of application.properties. I don't want to put my password in application.properties.
Maybe configure DataSource bean and set all values in it.

Do you want to put password in OS environment variable?

@Alex no configure using DataSource bean

I hope it will suit you
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
        dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:h2:mem:test");
        dataSourceBuilder.username("SA");
        dataSourceBuilder.password("");
        return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }
}

Remove this info from properties and write here. Be aware that hardcoded password is also unsecured, the code might be decompiled. It is better to read password from environment
dataSourceBuilder.password(System.getEnv("MY_PASSWORD")

This example is borrowed from https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-configure-data-source-programmatic
